# how to use access/stat to test if the mountpoint is ok or not?

Tags: c, linux, mount, ext4

I mounted a disk to a mountpoint, and I unplug the disk without umount.
I want to use access(mountpoint, R_OK | W_OK) to discover the disk is broken, but failed...

Here's my testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *dir = "/sdf";
    int ret;
    struct stat s;

    ret = access(dir, R_OK | W_OK);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("access ERROR: %s can not be read or write ret=%d\n", dir, ret);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("access INFO: %s can be read and write ret=%d\n", dir, ret);

    ret = stat(dir, &s);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("stat ERROR: %s can not be read or write ret=%d\n", dir, ret);
        return 0;
    }

    printf("stat INFO: %s can be read and write ret=%d\n", dir, ret);
    return 0;
}
```

here's the result:

```
[test]# ./access 
access INFO: /sdf can be read and write ret=0
stat INFO: /sdf can be read and write ret=0
```

I use ls to list the mountpoint:

```
[test]# ls /sdf
ls: reading directory /sdf: Input/output error
```

I dont know why this happen...

anyone can help me?

I use ext4 filesystem

```
[test]# mount |grep sdf
/root/loopfile.img on /sdf type ext4 (ro,relatime)
/dev/sdf on /sdf type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: I do not think you can use [`access()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) to check if a mount is okay. The check is quite possible, mind you; just not with `access()`.

Comment: in my opinion it is not sufficient to check the mountpoint access to decide whether the filesystem mounted to it is ok or not. If you don't have an API provided by the fs driver, perhaps you could do some read operations in the easisest case for this purpose. For example you can recursively read the directory listing under the mountpoint. But in this case you don't test file's content and don't test whether writing is ok.

Comment: besides that, just an idea. You can try to open some from the mounted filesystem for writting and then analyze the error code. Depending on your OS, you can also get EIO return code which will indicate yor case.

Comment: Is there another api can use to check the mountpoint?  I use a specifical file under the mountpoint to check if it's writable or not.